# Unexpected Errors With Parse and Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

So I am building this app in XCode in Swift and I get 56 unexpected errors that most likely has to do with something in Parse.

```
    Unexpected-Journey Group
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPinchGestureRecognizer.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPinchGestureRecognizer.h:23:23: Definition of 'CGAffineTransform' (aka 'struct CGAffineTransform') must be imported from module 'CoreText.CTFontDescriptor' before it is required
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBDialogs.h
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBDialogs.h:18:9: Could not build module 'UIKit'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBDialogs.h:114:52: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBDialogs.h:116:52: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBDialogs.h:146:52: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBDialogs.h:183:52: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBViewController.h
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBViewController.h:72:31: Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIViewController', superclass of 'FBViewController'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBViewController.h:80:40: Unknown type name 'UIBarButtonItem'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBViewController.h:80:31: Property with 'iboutlet' attribute must be an object type (invalid 'int *')
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBViewController.h:80:1: Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBViewController.h:88:40: Unknown type name 'UIBarButtonItem'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBViewController.h:88:31: Property with 'iboutlet' attribute must be an object type (invalid 'int *')
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBViewController.h:88:1: Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBViewController.h:102:41: Unknown type name 'UIView'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBViewController.h:102:1: Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBViewController.h:113:43: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBGraphObjectPickerViewController.h
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBGraphObjectPickerViewController.h:46:40: Unknown type name 'UIActivityIndicatorView'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBGraphObjectPickerViewController.h:46:31: Property with 'iboutlet' attribute must be an object type (invalid 'int *')
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBGraphObjectPickerViewController.h:46:1: Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBGraphObjectPickerViewController.h:52:40: Unknown type name 'UITableView'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBGraphObjectPickerViewController.h:52:31: Property with 'iboutlet' attribute must be an object type (invalid 'int *')
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBGraphObjectPickerViewController.h:52:1: Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBLikeControl.h
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBLikeControl.h:91:28: Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIControl', superclass of 'FBLikeControl'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBLikeControl.h:104:31: Unknown type name 'UIColor'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBLikeControl.h:104:1: Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:33:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/./FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:33:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBLoginView.h:21:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/./FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBLoginView.h:21:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBTooltipView.h
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBTooltipView.h:55:28: Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIView', superclass of 'FBTooltipView'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:33:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/./FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:33:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBLoginView.h:21:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/./FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBLoginView.h:21:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBTooltipView.h:111:26: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:33:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/./FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:33:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBLoginView.h:21:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/./FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBLoginView.h:21:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBTooltipView.h:124:24: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:33:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/./FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:33:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBLoginView.h
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBLoginView.h:54:26: Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIView', superclass of 'FBLoginView'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:34:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/./FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:34:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBNativeDialogs.h
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBNativeDialogs.h:70:40: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:34:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/./FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:34:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBNativeDialogs.h:82:40: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:34:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/./FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:34:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBNativeDialogs.h:94:40: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:39:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/./FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:39:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBProfilePictureView.h
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBProfilePictureView.h:48:35: Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIView', superclass of 'FBProfilePictureView'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:5:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:43:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/./FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FacebookSDK.h:43:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBSettings.h
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBSettings.h:18:2: Missing submodule 'CoreGraphics.CGBase'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/Parse.framework/Headers/PFConstants.h
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/Parse.framework/Headers/PFConstants.h:27:9: Could not build module 'UIKit'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:6:9: While building module 'Parse' imported from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:6:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/Parse.framework/Headers/PFPurchase.h:8:9: While building module 'StoreKit' imported from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/Parse.framework/Headers/PFPurchase.h:8:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/<module-includes>:1:9: In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/Headers/StoreKit.h:17:9: In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/Headers/StoreKit.h:17:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/Headers/SKStoreProductViewController.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/Headers/SKStoreProductViewController.h:9:9: Could not build module 'UIKit'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:6:9: Could not build module 'Parse'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:33:71: Expected ':'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:33:71: Expected ';' after method prototype
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:43:81: Expected ':'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:43:81: Expected ';' after method prototype
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:68:27: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:109:30: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:138:19: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:150:75: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:163:19: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:176:19: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:180:19: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:194:19: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:209:21: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:218:21: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:225:33: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:233:54: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:242:33: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:255:26: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:258:26: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:270:26: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:288:52: Expected ':'
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:288:52: Expected ';' after method prototype
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey/ParseFacebookUtils.framework/Headers/PFFacebookUtils.h:82:60: Expected a type
/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: In file included from /Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h:7:
Failed to import bridging header '/Users/peterliz/Documents/Unexpected-Journey/Unexpected-Journey-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Also I get this error in the bridging header which I think is the cause of all this.

Cannot Build Module 'Parse'

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h> 
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

Comment: Could you post the bridging header? It looks like a syntax error in that file.

Comment: The bridging header is the code with the 3 import lines I posted above. It was working before but now it has all these errors when I go back on. Really would like to get this fixed.